# PostgreSQL statement timeout

Tags: postgresql

PostgreSQL Version: 9.3

We have online system which gets transnational data (approximately 15000 records per day).

We have table partitioning on date & time and have a PostgreSQL function to load the incoming request into the table.

Sometimes we see the error message

> ERROR: 57014: canceling statement due to statement timeout

The client sends the request again after some time if not successful and on second try it gets recorded successfully.  It seems this has to be something with table locks but I am not sure.

Comment: `ALTER USER your_user SET statement_timeout=0` and add `VACUUM ANALYZE VERBOSE;`?

Comment: Thanks @dwir182.  statement_timeout  we can change but client expects real-time response within 5-10 seconds which always works but only in few cases it times out. But will try VACUUM ANALYZE

Comment: you will need to show us the slow queries if you want to improve them. There is no magic knob that makes everything go faster.

Comment: Postgres 9.3 is [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/) you should plan your upgrade to a supported version as soon as possible. Given the substantial performance improvements that were made in the last 5 years since 9.3 was released that might even solve (some of) your performance problems.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name,  Thanks for the comments. Its not slow query. Same query on 2nd retry works faster as expected and completes execution within 2-3 seconds. Only sometimes it is slow which still cant understand why. And yes, we must plan the upgrade very soon

Comment: @Jayadeep: sounds like a caching issue. You might want to increase the memory on the server to make sure all important data is always cached. Or buy faster harddisks (SSDs can make a big difference if the data can't be kept in memory completely). If this happens right after e.g. a startup of the database server, you could look into the "pg prewarm" extension that ensures that the caches are filled after a startup (however I am not sure if that was already available in 9.3)

Comment: Is it have pattern when error will show up?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, I will try these options as well. Thanks.

Comment: @dwir182, No specific pattern, but normally at the peak time we see this issue

Comment: What you actually called peak are the pattern..

Comment: During peak time, server will receive too many requests at  the same time. Then we will see this issue. But again during the same peak time if it receives the same request again, then it will work.

Answer (score 3):

Set `log_lock_waits = on` in `postgresql.conf` and see if you get log entries. That would tell you that a query is hanging for more than one second.

Answer (score -5):

For me, I have this error while developing a model in odoo 16, i couldn't update the model, so I restart the database with this command :

```
sudo service postgresql restart
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, including a detailed explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @ShawnHemelstrand, this code works for me, I will edit this post for more detailed